# Ansible does not install dependency from Git SCM

Tags: git, apache, vagrant, ansible, ansible-role

I am trying to create a new Ansible role called "Adminer" which requires the "Apache" role.

I've specified the Apache role as a dependency in `meta/main.yml`:

```
---
dependencies:
  - src: git+https@github.com:alexandrubau/ansible-apache.git
    name: apache
```

I'm testing the Adminer role using Vagrant and I get the following error:

```
vagrant provision
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Running provisioner: ansible_local...
Vagrant has automatically selected the compatibility mode '2.0'
according to the Ansible version installed (2.4.2.0).

Alternatively, the compatibility mode can be specified in your Vagrantfile:
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_common.html#compatibility_mode

    default: Running ansible-playbook...
ERROR! the role 'apache' was not found in /vagrant/tests/roles:/home/vagrant/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles:/:/vagrant/tests

The error appears to have been in '/vagrant/meta/main.yml': line 3, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

dependencies:
  - src: https://github.com/alexandrubau/ansible-apache.git
    ^ here

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

**Shouldn't Ansible download the new role from the supplied git repo?**

Here's my Vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

$script = <<SCRIPT
mkdir -p /etc/ansible/roles
ln -f -s /vagrant /etc/ansible/roles/test-role
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

config.vm.box       = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
config.vm.hostname  = "ansible-test.local"
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.13.37"
config.vm.synced_folder "../", "/vagrant"

config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vbox|
    vbox.memory = 2048
    vbox.cpus   = 2
end

config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script

config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
    ansible.inventory_path    = "tests/inventory"
    ansible.playbook          = "tests/test.yml"
    ansible.limit             = "localhost"
end
end
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: There is a lot missing from the question, but `The error appears to have been in '/vagrant/meta/main.yml'` -- your file is not treated as a part of a role (in which case it should rather show `/etc/ansible/roles/test-role/meta/main.yml`), but somehow called directly as a playbook/tasks file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems that the `meta/main.yml` file is being read only by the `ansible-galaxy` command, when you install a role.

This is stated in the [official Ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy.html#dependencies):

> When dependencies are encountered by `ansible-galaxy`, it will automatically install each dependency to the `roles_path`. To understand how dependencies are handled during play execution, see...

I found the workaround by using `requirements.yml` file and running it with:
`ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml`